# Position div depending on the height of another div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `<div>` (let's call it "image") that contains some images `<img><img><img>` and so on.
This div's width is set at 100% of the screen, and the images inside rescale depending on the width. So, depending on the browser's width, the height of my div changes.

Now I would like to create another div (let's call it "after_image") that starts after this image, without using "relative", but by retrieving the height of `<div id="image">`, and using that as a "top: px" attribute.

Is it possible? Maybe a `<script>`?
(I am using PHP)

Comment: this will cause issues if you assign a fixed value to the `after_image { top`, then resize the page, unless you constantly update the `top` value on every resize event. is there a reason you want to assign it a pixel value instead of letting the browser handle it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```html
<div id='image'>
  <img src='' />
  <img src='' />
  <img src='' />
</div>
<div id='after_image'></div>

<script>
  var h = document.getElementById('image').clientHeight // returns height as number
  document.getElementById('after_image').style.top = h + 'px'
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can achieve what you want, although this is the wrong approach in my opinion.

```js
const
  image = document.querySelector('#image'),
  after = document.querySelector('#after_image')
  
after.style.top = image.getBoundingClientRect().bottom + 'px'
```

```css
#image {
  width: 200px;
  height: 2750px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid blue 3px;
  background: skyblue;
}

#after_image {
  width: 200px;
  height: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid orangered 3px;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div id='image'>
  <img src='' />
</div>
<div id='after_image'></div>
```

If you really want to do it this way, it is best to bind your JS statement to the `resize` event.

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
  after.style.top = image.getBoundingClientRect().bottom + 'px'
}
```

Comment: Thanks Anthony. What way do you recommend instead of the above?

Comment: @LucaDanieli i would recommend just letting the browser handle it via `position: relative`. why cant you use `position: relative`?

Comment: @LucaDanieli also, if these answers are helpful to you, you should be voting them up or marking as solved.

Comment: I can to that, but <div style="position:relative"></div><div style="position:relative"></div> are placed at the same absolute top value regardless of the first div's height

Comment: @LucaDanieli if theyre both positioned relatively, they wont be placed absolutely nor in the exact same position

Comment: They are, unfortunately. I understood it is because the first div has only <img> tags inside, and somehow it considers the div as having 0px height. Therefore it makes sense that if height=0, they get positioned in the same place. If I add a letter after the <img> tags, the second div gets positioned correctly (with an additional space given to the height of the letter).

Comment: @LucaDanieli if an element has a height of `0` and does not inherit height from one of its children, it wont even display on the screen. if a `div` has an `img` element inside of it, the height of the `div` will not be `0`, unless the height of the image is actually `0`. where are you hearing this stuff?